# live data chart not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

hi everyone im working on real-time java script chart to display data from a database but all i get is nothing its not catching data from data base

i used this php code

```
   <?php

    header("Content-type: text/json");
   $servername = "localhost"; 
   $username = "root";  
   $password = "";
   $value = $_GET['value'];
   $date = time() * 1000;
   $ret = array($date, $value);
   echo json_encode($ret);
   $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
 if ($conn) {
 echo "Connected successfully";
} 
else {
 echo "connection failed";
} 
$conndb = mysql_select_db('database', $conn);
echo  "<br>";
$sql_insert ="insert into pulsesensor(value) values ('$value')";
if($sql_insert){
echo "insert successfull";
}
else {
echo "insert failed";
  }   echo  "<br>";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_insert);
     if($result){
         echo "insert successfull";
         }
         else {
         echo "insert failed" . mysql_error($result);
         }
        ?>
```

and for real-time chart i used this code

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 
     auto">
     </div>
```

```
/**
* Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout 
* to request again
*/
function requestData() {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'mysql0.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[0],
            shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                             // longer than 20
        // add the point
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

        // call it again after one second
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
    },
     cache: false
   });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live Heartbeats data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
    },
    yAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        title: {
            text: 'Value',
            margin: 80
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'heartbeats data',
         data: []
       }]
    });        
});
        </script>
```

at the end the result is this [image]

Comment: what's your `mysql0.php`? If you open developer tools, and look at the network tab, does your script send requests? Does it get anything back? How does the data that it gets back look like? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @Dimi  
my mysql0.php is my php code to send data to the server ,, the data send and insert correctly to the database but i don't know if it back correctly and i have a website display database values as a table and this also work idk why the java script cant see the values

Comment: Paste data output from your server.